# Is the "virtual" keyword optional in base classes in C++?

Tags: c++, virtual, keyword

I'm trying to understand the function of the "virtual" keyword in C++ - consider this example:

```
#ifdef USE_VIRTUAL
struct a {
  virtual void say_hi() { std::cout << "hello from a" << std::endl; }
};
#else
struct a {
  void say_hi() { std::cout << "hello from a" << std::endl; }
};
#endif

struct b : public a {
  void say_hi() { std::cout << "hello from b" << std::endl; }
};

int main( int argc, char** argc )
{
  a a_obj;
  b b_obj;
  a_obj.say_hi();
  b_obj.say_hi();
}
```

This program outputs:

```
hello from a
hello from b
```

regardless of whether or not a::say_hi is declared as virtual or not. Since the function gets correctly overridden even when say_hi is not declared virtual, then what is the function of declaring it as virtual?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You aren't using polymorphism. Polymorphic behaviour only affects pointers and references to base classes, like so:

```
class A; class B1 : A; class B2 : A;

B1 x;
B2 y;
A  z;

A & a1 = x;  // static type A&, dynamic type B1&
A & a2 = y;  // static type A&, dynamic type B2&
A & a3 = z;  // static and dynamic type A&
```

Now accessing member functions of `a1`, `a2`, `a3` is subject to polymorphism and virtual dispatch.

*However*, you must declare the first function at the top of the inheritance hierarchy virtual, i.e. in `A`! In your example, without `virtual`, there's no polymorphism and you always call the member function of the corresponding *static* type of the object. To test this, add another few lines:

```
a & bref = b_obj;
bref.say_hi();       // call b::say_hi() if virtual, a::say_hi if not
bref.a::say_hi();    // always call a::say_hi()
```

Comment: Interesting... I was (erroneously, obviously) expecting the compiler to complain if I tried to override a non-virtual function, like C#. Thanks for clearing that up for me.

Comment: That's because you're not overriding, you're *hiding* the base function. That's permissible, so the compiler assumes you know what you're doing (indeed, this isn't C# :-)). In C++11 you can add the `override` keyword to declare your intent explicitly, in which case you'll even get a nice compiler error.

Comment: Hah, OK. I obviously need to head back to my C++ textbook. Thanks!

Comment: @Chris: Well, everything (sort of) is a reference in C#, so you're always eligible for dynamic dispatch. But all the same polymorphism is only *interesting* if you refer to a derived object through a reference to a base object. In your example, reference or not, and virtual or not, you would always get the same output that you have.